# WooCommerce products ordered by categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce attribute archive pages where I need to show the products sorted by category. Like so:

### Category A

- Product X
- Product Y
- Product Z

### Category B

- Product A
- Product B
- Product C

etc.

What the result of my current custom loop is now:

### Category A

- Product A
- Product B
- Product C
- Product X
- Product Y
- Product Z

### Category B

- Product A
- Product B
- Product C
- Product X
- Product Y
- Product Z

etc.

So it is basically showing all products within the attribute term within every category, even if the product is not even in this category. I think I am overlooking something, but I can't figure out what?

```
<?php
/**
 * Show products sorted by category
 */

$taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
$orderby        = 'menu_order';
$order          = 'ASC';
$show_count     = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts     = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical   = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title          = '';
$empty          = 1; // 1 for hide, 0 for show

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'       => $orderby,
    'order'         => $order,
    'show_count'    => $show_count,
    'pad_counts'    => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical'  => $hierarchical,
    'title_li'      => $title,
    'hide_empty'    => $empty,
);

$all_categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ($all_categories as $cat) :

    $term_link = get_term_link( $cat );

    if( $cat->category_parent == 0 ) :

        $category_id    = $cat->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id   = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image          = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        echo '<div id="' . $cat->slug . '" class="category ' . $cat->slug . '"><h2 class="category-title"><a href="'. esc_url( $term_link ) .'">'.$cat->name.'</a></h2>';

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                global $product;

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- end .category -->

            <?php

            wp_reset_query();

        endif;

    endforeach;

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

add below code for fetch category wise product

```
    <?php
/**
 * Show products sorted by category
 */

$taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
$orderby        = 'menu_order';
$order          = 'ASC';
$show_count     = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts     = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical   = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title          = '';
$empty          = 1; // 1 for hide, 0 for show


$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'       => $orderby,
    'order'         => $order,
    'show_count'    => $show_count,
    'pad_counts'    => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical'  => $hierarchical,
    'title_li'      => $title,
    'hide_empty'    => $empty,
);




$all_categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ($all_categories as $cat) :

    $term_link = get_term_link( $cat );

    if( $cat->category_parent == 0 ) :

        $category_id    = $cat->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id   = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image          = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        echo '<div id="' . $cat->slug . '" class="category ' . $cat->slug . '"><h2 class="category-title"><a href="'. esc_url( $term_link ) .'">'.$cat->name.'</a></h2>';

            $product_args = array(
                'type'          => 'product',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'DESC',
                'pad_counts'    => false,
                'hierarchical'  => 1,
                'hide_empty'    => 0,
                'tax_query'                => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $cat->term_id
                    )
                ),
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $product_args );

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                global $product;

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- end .category -->

            <?php

            wp_reset_query();

        endif;

    endforeach;

    wp_reset_query();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Argument for [get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) and [WP_Query()](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) are different.

Argument for get product categories wise.

```
$args_for_product = array(
            'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' =>$taxonomy,'field' => 'slug','terms' =>$cat->slug)),
            'orderby'       => $orderby,
            'order'         => $order,
);
```

used `tax_query` for pass the categories in product query. other argument (**like `show_count,pad_counts,hierarchical,title_li,hide_empty` are not pass in WP_Query**) not need. put above code in category loop

also change in `while` loop `have_post()` to `$loop->have_post()` and `the_post()` to `$loop->the_post()`

> Complete code

```
<?php
/**
 * Show products sorted by category
 */

$taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
$orderby        = 'menu_order';
$order          = 'ASC';
$show_count     = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts     = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical   = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title          = '';
$empty          = 1; // 1 for hide, 0 for show

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
    'orderby'       => $orderby,
    'order'         => $order,
    'show_count'    => $show_count,
    'pad_counts'    => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical'  => $hierarchical,
    'title_li'      => $title,
    'hide_empty'    => $empty,
);

$all_categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ($all_categories as $cat) :

    $term_link = get_term_link( $cat );

    if( $cat->category_parent == 0 ) :

        $category_id    = $cat->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id   = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image          = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        echo '<div id="' . $cat->slug . '" class="category ' . $cat->slug . '"><h2 class="category-title"><a href="'. esc_url( $term_link ) .'">'.$cat->name.'</a></h2>';

        $args_for_product = array('type'=> 'product',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' =>$taxonomy,'field' => 'slug','terms' =>$cat->slug)),
            'orderby'       => $orderby,
            'order'         => $order,
        );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args_for_product );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                global $product;

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- end .category -->

            <?php

            wp_reset_query();

        endif;

    endforeach;

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for, but the only problem is that this code shows all categories and products within that category. I want to display the loop on an attribute term archive page, so I only want to show the products that have term 'foo' in attribute 'bar'. So there must be an extra argument there to filter out the unnecessary products?

Comment: i am not understand what are you saying. but here are list of all argument pass in wp_Query - https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/ to filter product

Comment: @JustinPicard above code is working fine as per you categories query. please explain more about your query.

Comment: My shop sells and rents machines. Those machines have an attribute called 'state'. In that state there are the terms 'new', 'used' and 'for rent'. What my code did was displaying the correct machines that belong to the term on the page. E.g. I have 3 machines in 3 different categories that have the term 'for rent'. The attribute term archive page 'for rent' groups all 3 products in the same category, and it loops through all categories, even categories that do not match any of the 3 products. See [this example screenshot](https://ibb.co/dwmCjk)

Comment: @JustinPicard in categories loop there are not any option for check product attribute, so it loop through all the available categories.